# Websockets for pushing events from server to client in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, events, architecture, websocket

I have a scenario where a webclient has to be updated whenever certain things change on the server. For this I have, on the server side, either

- an infinite loop that actively collects changes
- a callback, an eventlistener, hooked into an other system/framework/class with an eventloop

When this mechanism finds a change or receives an event, it needs to pass it on to the webclient over the websocket.

While this is straightforward e.g. in Java where you have the concept of a "running app" thanks to eventloops (threads), this doesn't map that well to PHP. PHP is designed to serve HTTP requests, stateless by nature. When a request comes in, a PHP scripts gets executed, does stuff and renders a response, then dissolves into voidness.

How can I get a serverside PHP process running that does the event listening and provides the means for webclients to open a websocket connection with it? Much like an independently started thread where eventlisteners can subscribe to?

Possible solutions I can think of:

**Scenario A: PHP threads (pthreads)**

If PHP threads were used, is this how it works?

- Webclient A makes a request
- On the server side a new thread is started holding the websocket connection and doing the listening work
- The "normal" response/request thread (the one that spawned the eventlistening thread) ends after sending back a response
- Client and server are now connected. Client A now has its own thread running on the server
- When webclient B makes a request, same happens exclusively for him/her, thus creating a new thread, possibly doing the same job as the first from A

**Scenario B: CRON**

To simulate the eventloop, a CRON job could be setup to run a PHP script at a certain interval. While that does the job of gathering the events that are of interest to the clients, how do you get hold of the websocket endpoints? As this PHP script runs independently of the Web, how do you join it to the open (?) sockets? Someone has to keep hold of them...

**If PHP is a bad match for websockets due to it's "script design", what would be a good alternative?**

Comment: Have you thought about using node.js?

Comment: php is not multi-threaded language...

Comment: @MarcB: Correct, but there is the [pthread extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)

Comment: @MarcB **yes, it is ...**

Comment: Pthreads is incredible but I just cannot get it to work with websockets (ratchet specifically). I can pass a mysql resource to a thread worker but not a websocket resource. I get a cannot serialize closure message in addition to the resource just ceasing to exist (regardless if I pass the resource to a thread or not). I'm going to post this as a question actually.

Answer (score 0):

Ratchet is a great php websocket server: http://socketo.me/

This is what I do:

```
$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher();

// run ratchet as a daemon @ 0.5 second intervals
$loop->addPeriodicTimer(0.50, function() use($pusher){
    //$thread = new AsyncThread\AsyncThread($pusher->clients); // Really wished this worked, but everytime i send a websocket resource to a thread the thread throws a fatal error if i attempt to bind the data and even if I dont the resource disappears /sigh
    $pusher->load(); // so I just call this function which basically handles each client one after the other as opposed to simultaneously via threads.
});

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);

if ($loop instanceof \React\EventLoop\LibEventLoop) {
    echo "\n HAS LibEvent"; // apparently performance is better with the libevent php extension callback installed; I haven't really noticed a significant difference
}

$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer($pusher)
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```